# Weird encoding issue when posting data

Tags: php, curl, post

Hey there guys I am getting this weird encoding issue I am unable to find the solution

the problem is i am making a curl request with certain errors

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array("header1:value","header2:value2"));
```

the above code works fine but the problem comes when i post these headers
Headers are posted in this format
header1:value
header2:value

```
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_URL, "example.com" );
curl_setopt( $ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, explode("\n",$_POST["custom_header"]));
```

I get no response means the correct headers where not sent so what could be the issue it works fine when I put a static value but not from post value.

Comment: Try `$headers = explode("\n",$_POST["custom_header"]); var_dump($headers);` before the `curl_setopt()` and see if the result is what you think it is. You should also be extensively validating _any_ user input before putting using it into other function calls like this.

Comment: @Sammitch its valid its some kind of encoding issue

Comment: Do these header values contain arabic or other non-ascii text?

Comment: @Sammitch Nop nohing that the problem can understand what happening

Comment: Then I'm out of guesses. You're going to need to post examples of the header data.